# Jmeter should execute queries in concurrently but same time query should not repeat in parallel threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to run below scenario with Jmeter, is it possible?. Please help on this

## Scenario

I have  20  queries, These queries should run concurrently with 5 threads and  each thread should complete all 20 queries.

But at any given point time all threads should run different queries (.i.e one thread query should not match with other query).

Answer (score 1):

This is a great reason for using [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

> The Critical Section Controller ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a named lock will be taken before executing children of controller.

Insert Critical Section Controller as a parent for each query with **different lock name** and by that each query will be execute once at a time

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where do you keep these "queries" the options are in:

1. Use i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to remove the "current" query from the list prior to executing the query with the given thread and [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to add the query back to the list after the execution is done. Make sure to store the queries globally using JMeter Properties.
2. Use [HTTP Simple Table](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) server for the same given the same approach: remove the query from the list before starting and adding it back after request finishes. You can install HTTP Simple Table server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).